# Error unbound identifier in pattern matching in Scheme

Tags: regex, scheme, pattern-matching

I'm a beginner in Scheme programming and currently i'm learning pattern matching.

I found an example in the book [Simply Scheme: Introducing Computer Science](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch16/match.html)

Example:

```
(match '(* me *) '(love me do)))
```

I execute this code in DrRacket, Why I have an error:

```
love: unbound identifier in module in: love
```

Their output is `#t`

So can someone please explain this problem for me??? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you link to seems to have its own pattern matching, did you actually `(load "match.scm")` from [here?](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch16/)

Otherwise, you're using Racket's build-in `match`, and you should code for example as follows:

```
(match '(love me do)
  ((list _ 'me _) #t)
  (else           #f))
```

Documentation is [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html).